Where Does the Short-Circuit Voltage Drop to 0V? What Happens to the Voltage at the Green Branch Point?
Currently, I am considering an electrical circuit where the distance from the power source to the short-circuit point is 10 meters, using a VVF cable with a diameter of 2mm. The red point represents the location of the short circuit, and the green point is a branch point. My question is why the voltage at the short-circuit point drops to 0V and what happens to the voltage at the green branch point (between the ground terminal and the ungrounded terminal) when this occurs.

Your circuit is a limiting case of the following circuit.
You have a voltage source V1 with non-zero output resistance Rs (since real power supplies can't have zero internal resistance, Rs must be greater than 0). Two load resistors, R1 and R2 at the output side in parallel.
R1 can represent your voltmeter (with an extremely large resistance, ideally infinity, realistically \$ 10 \cdot 10^6 \text{ }\Omega \$), and R2 is the load.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
What is the voltage across the resistor R1? By visual inspection, R1 and R2 are in parallel, and both are in series with Rs. Using the formula for a voltage divider, the voltage across resistor R1 is given by:
$$
V_{R1} = V_1 \cdot \frac{R_1 \parallel R_2}{R_S + (R_1 \parallel R_2) }
$$
Note that \$ R1 \parallel R2 \$ is a shorthand for two resistances in parallel:
$$
R_1 \parallel R_2 = \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}} = \dfrac{R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_1 + R_2}
$$
Now, consider the case in which R2 is a short circuit:
$$
\lim_{R_2 \to 0} R_1 \parallel R2 = \lim_{R_2 \to 0} \dfrac{R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_1 + R_2} = \dfrac{R_1 \cdot 0}{R_1 + 0} = 0
$$
So the voltage across resistor R1 reduces to:
$$
V_{R1} = \lim_{R_2 \to 0} V_1 \cdot \frac{R_1 \parallel R_2}{R_S + (R_1 \parallel R_2) } = V_1 \cdot \frac{0}{R_S + 0 } = 0
$$
The voltage across resistor R1 is always zero, regardless of the value of R1. This answers your question.
Finally, some remarks:

I analyzed the full three-resistor circuit for completeness.  But the resistance of voltmeters are large, R1 is ideally infinite, the voltage across R1 and R2 are considered the same. So one can ignore R1, reducing this problem to a simple two-resistor circuit.
$$
V_{R2} = V_1 \cdot \frac{R_2}{R_S + R_2}
$$

If an ideal voltage source with zero source resistance (Rs = 0) is connected to a short circuit (R2 = 0), note how the voltage divider equation has the indeterminate form \$ \dfrac{0}{0} \$. This is why connecting the positive and negative terminals of an ideal voltage source is illegal in circuit analysis, since it creates a division by zero with infinite current. To model real voltage sources with physical behaviors, a non-zero output resistance must always be assumed.


For a more realistic analysis, consider the fact that voltmeter R1 and load R2 are connected by wires with non-zero resistance. One can use R3 to represent the small but non-zero wiring resistance:

simulate this circuit
The voltage at resistor R1 is given by:
$$
V_{R1} = V_1 \cdot \frac{R_1 \parallel (R_2 + R_3) }{R_S + [R_1 \parallel (R_2 + R_3)] }
$$
Since the resistance of voltmeters are large, R1 is infinite so it can be ignored:
$$
V_{R1} = V_1 \cdot \frac{R_2 + R_3}{R_S + R_2 + R_3}
$$
When R2 is short-circuited, it's reduced to 0, while the wiring resistance R3 remains. But R3 is typically extremely small. As long as R3 is much smaller than Rs (e.g. by an order of magnitude, which is true since the wires are closer to us than the distribution transformers of the power grid), the voltage across the voltmeter R1 will be very close to 0 V.

Well the definition of short circuit is that there is zero resistance, so regardless of the short circuit current flowing you'll have 0 V (ideally) because of the zero resistance (ideally)
The voltage between the green nodes depends on the short circuit current \$ i_{sc}\$ and the resistance (in general case of the impedance) of the wiring \$ R_{w}\$ from those nodes to the short circuit. The voltae drop will be \$R_{w} \cdot i_{sc}\$
